# Some Security patches Shows Error executing check in magereport

Tags: magento-1.9, patches

I have checked my URL in mage report for security patch but it has shown Error executing check message in some security patch. so I want to know why this type of message comes from magerepot and how to solve it.My Magento version is Magento 1.9.2.2
**Note:** I have to try to install security patch but still I am getting the same error.
[image]

**From the comment of Christoph Farnleitner,I use this link https://github.com/magesec/magesecuritypatcher but getting this error.**
[image]

Comment: same problem here!!

Comment: I also tried to change core file and all things but still facing the same error, please help someone solve this error.

Comment: Hello Guys, Please answer this question.                                                                 i am facing the same error in my two websites. So, Is it mandatory to install this patch or not??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first:

Please note that the test on https://www.magereport.com is not capable of highly conclusively checking customized shops and even has troubles of checking particular patches if certain other patches are installed. Therefore you must understand that MageReport.com - even though I highly appreciate there effort and still would like to recommend using this tool as a quick, first check - is NO ultimate, omnipotent testing tool and only can work within certainly given limitations.

As an example:
In your case magereport.com is not able to figure out what version of Magento you're using. This check is based on its own Version Identification using hashes of some static files (see [gwillem/magento-version-identification on GitHub](https://github.com/gwillem/magento-version-identification)).

***Edit:** For those of you who want to run the version check by yourself you may be interested in the equivalent [steverobbins/magento-version-identification-php on GitHub](https://github.com/steverobbins/magento-version-identification-php). Installation and usage is described in the help page (though I wont post it here since this in my opinion is not relevant to the actual question).*

Basically, the disclaimer ([FAQs on MageReport.com](https://www.magereport.com/page/faq)) already tells a lot about the process:

> It's our first priority to make our security checks accurate. While we
>   thoroughly test and constantly tweak our security checks, we cannot
>   guarantee that the results are always 100% accurate. Every Magento
>   store is different, and in some scenarios, the configuration of your
>   store or server may lead to false positives or negatives. Therefore,
>   we advise you to use MageReport as a guide. If you are unsure about
>   the validity of a check, please consult your developer or find one on
>   the support page.

***Edit:** What you could do, in case this is applicable for you is to specify the actual backend URL (in case your backend is not reachable at "/admin"). However, I strongly believe that your main problem is the fact that there is some mismatch in your file hashes - in worst case due to core file changes! This said MageReport.com might fail since it can not check for applied differences since it doesn't know what to look for in your setup (because it would need to check for EVERY Magento version available...). You can determine if this is the case for example by using the [Magento Security Council's Integrity check available on GitHub](https://github.com/magesec/projectintegrity).*

---

However, in order to address your situation a bit more clearly as MageReport.com (in general) is able to determine the state of the mentioned patches:
Applying patches:
I would assume you checked on this but first of all you must make sure that the particular patch is actually applied **completely**. Especially if a patch was not applied via SSH but manually by modifying files based on diffs or similar approaches.

Custom themes:
"Completely" already brings me to the next topic. When patching a shop you will patch exclusively the files Magento ships with. That being said any custom skins/themes (i.e. templates residing in folders such as `app/design/frontend/rwd/my-style` or `app/design/frontend/my-shop/my-style`) will NOT BE PATCHED! You will ALWAYS have to apply changes on them manually by checking what a given patch is actually changing and integrate these changes into your theme.

Custom modules:
The exactly same thing applies on any custom module - self-written or purchased. If you, as an example, are overwriting a particular function that got patched by a "SUPEE" you must make sure that this change is reflected in your custom code as well.

Alternatives to patching you shop the "common way":

Security patcher from 'Magento security council: https://github.com/magesec/magesecuritypatcher

> Mage Security Patcher is a more effective alternative to the standard
>   magento patches. Patching Magento is prone to failure because you are
>   applying patches over patches, and sometimes even multiple versions of
>   patches. Figuring out what patches you need and what versions is also
>   painful and error prone.
>
> Instead, this patcher updates the entire Magento installation to a
>   fully patched state - automatically. It works 100% of the time,
>   because instead of applying individual patches and building up patched
>   files, it patches your Magento installation directly to the final
>   state of having all patches applied. It also adds in form keys to
>   custom templates that would not be included in the standard patch
>   libraries.

Full update:
Rather than patching a shop it is always an option to run a complete update.

**Both alternatives however still require you to make sure that any customization is in tune with the given Magento version / patch state.**

Comment: Where did you find this article can you give reference link ? From where did you find answer @Christoph Farnleitner

Comment: I updated answer, please see and help me with it.

Comment: @Christoph Farnleitner I have checked (https://github.com/gwillem/magento-version-identification) link but how can I run this. please, can you explain it?

Comment: @Jaimin - I'm happy to clarify and improve my post, may you just tell me, in what reference you're interested (or in references on what particular topic)?

Comment: Thanks for you reply @ChristophFarnleitner i find out that article in magerepot website.

Comment: Actually I have checked (github.com/gwillem/magento-version-identification) link but how can I run this. please, can you explain it

Comment: @Jaimin - If you'd like to run the check as a PHP script you may refer to https://github.com/steverobbins/magento-version-identification-php as this might be easier

Comment: @AkashPatel, since you got the same question, please se above

Comment: @AkashPatel - I've added an additional note related to another possible reason for the version check to fail (namely "core changes").